OpenCV-Python overlapping boundingRect()
I'm trying to fix a bug where when two rects collide in a video, they merge into one big rectangle for the remaining frames that they collide, instead of keeping the rectangles as before:
Before collision:

After collision:

I want to keep both of the rectangles even when the objects collide.
Main loop snippet:
while True:
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    # TRESH_OTSU has problems with objects that are very dark
    bright_frame = cv2.addWeighted(
        frame, 4.3, np.zeros(frame.shape, frame.dtype), 0, 20
    )

    # create a mask that will remove the black background from tracking
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(bright_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # get the moving objects
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    detections = []
    for obj in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(obj)
        if area > 50:  # filter noise
            perimeter = cv2.arcLength(obj, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(obj, 0.02 * perimeter, True)
            object_type = "rectangle" if len(approx) == 4 else "circle"
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(obj)
            detections.append(
                DetectedObject(
                    x, y, w, h, get_obj_color(frame, x, y, w, h), object_type
                )
            )

    rects = tracker.update(detections)
    for rect in rects:
        x, y, w, h, id, _, _, time = rect
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 5)
        # cv2.putText(
        #     frame, str(id), (x, y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 5, (255, 255, 255)
        # )
        print(rect)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)

    # break the loop upon the press of esc
    if key == 27:
        break


Where does your code go wrong? You have not told us what is the issue with your code. Why does it not work?

use cv2.inRange to filter each object onto a seperate mask and get their bounding boxes there...

@fmw42 instead of keeping the rectangles separate when  colliding, it creates one big rectangle as shown in the description, i dont want that

@TinoD this would be very inefficient wouldnt it?

@banan for your purposes the absolute time difference will be very unnoticeable

@tinod but i would need to create a mask for every object? i dont quite get what are you  trying to suggest

how many objects are you expecting? In this case maybe better to get connected elements instead of contours?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here's an illustration of what I mean. I did a small example because you did not supply an unprocessed image:
Separated:

Colliding:

The approach is pretty simple:

define boundaries
apply cv2.inRange
get positive pixels and get bounding rectangle

For the separated:

For colliding:

Code snippet:
# define boundary for first object
lower1 = (150,90,30)
upper1 = (170,110,60)
# define boundary for second object
lower2 = (150,150,150)
upper2 = (255,255,255)
# get bounding boxes
boundingRect1 = cv2.boundingRect(cv2.inRange(im,lower1,upper1))
boundingRect2 = cv2.boundingRect(cv2.inRange(im,lower2,upper2))
# draw rectangle on im
cv2.rectangle(im, boundingRect1, (255,0,0), 5)
cv2.rectangle(im, boundingRect2, (0,0,255), 5)

Am not sure how many objects you will eventually have, nor am I sure that the two objects can be necessarily separated colour-wise. Eventually look at connected components if you always have clean object like photos
